# Is it possible for Evince to print PDFs "3-up"?

Tags: printing, pdf, evince

I would like to print a PDF from Evince with three-pages-to-one. With Adobe Reader 9.5.5, it's possible to do this:

[image: reader-3-up]

But Evince uses a different print setup (of course), which only allows printing "per page" 1, 2, 4, 6, 9, or 16 sides:

[image: evince-print]

Given it can manage 6-up, it seems odd that there is no option to print 3-up, or use "custom" sides-per-page settings.

This wouldn't be an issue for me if the (work) printer I (have to) use (a Sharp MX 2640N, if that matters) would duplex print jobs sent from Adobe Reader, but it won't. It duplexes Evince print jobs just fine.

So, is there a way to convince Evince to accept 3:1 page layouts? I live in hope.

Comment: Evince is using the gtk library - where those choices are hardcoded see:    https://github.com/GNOME/gtk/blob/master/gtk/gtkprintunixdialog.c line 2730

Comment: Bummer. :(  I've sent a message to the Evince dev list (linked from a helpful, but now deleted comment), so maybe it will be picked up there -- and possibly this question will be closed. We'll see, but thanks for the info.

Comment: I might have been mistaken as far as getting that to work.  I am looking into compiling a new gtk but adding the ability for a 3:1 print based on the link provided by jhilmer.  It might be as simple as changing the c file then compiling.

Comment: @Terrance - That would be terrific. Given the other options, it seems an odd one to omit. Thanks for looking into it!

Comment: @Dɑvïd I have now sent the Evince support a message about the possibility of adding at least the Custom Pages Per Sheet option in there like a lot of other applications have.  I have been looking over the code all day long and it must be embedded deeper in the application, as well as I have been looking at the GTK+ 3.0 source code as well and can only find what is listed there right now.  It does seem to me that the custom is controlled by the application developer.

Comment: Thanks so much, @Terrance, for the energy you put into this. Especially if your suggestion of custom layout (as in e.g. Adobe Reader, and other apps) or even 3:1 is added, that would be a welcome enhancement of Evince. Let's hope it happens!